# Hiding iAds when loading?

Tags: iphone, ios, unity-game-engine, iad

I'm trying to make an ios app with an iAd in the bottom but lifted a little bit. It actually woks ok but when the iAd is loading it shows an white area just below where the iAd should be. When its done loading the iAd jumps up in the right position.

I think normaly the button is loaded outside the screen and nthen pop ups when done but because mine add is liftet a little I can see the loading area...

Is there a way to make the iAd load in the sides instead and then popin from the side?

Here is what I have so far:

```
frame.origin.x = ( _screenWidth - frame.size.width ) / 2;

  if( calculateForBannerOnBottom )
   frame.origin.y = _screenHeight - (frame.size.height/1.2);
  else
   frame.origin.y = -_adView.frame.size.height+(frame.size.height/2.4);
```

Hoping 4 help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Basically, the iAd is drawn in a view and then slid on from the side. You'll probably have to re-write the deprecated animation code to take advantage of animation blocks.

Todd